# When adding google tag script in website, functionality not working

Tags: javascript

When i add google tag manager script in my wordpress website, user login, checkout functionalities facing issue.I tried with child theme as well as added script using plugins (google-tag-manage, insert-headers-and-footers), but issue s there. When we remove tag manager code, site working fine.

WordPress version 5.3.2

Comment: You'll probably have to debug this yourself sorry. When you are facing issues, are there any errors in the browser console? Is there anything the script might conflict with? Do you still have issues if you switch your site to a default WordPress or WooCommerce theme, or disable other plugins? Does the script added by your plugin look correct?

Comment: i used Google Tag Manager for Wordpress plugin for add script, and i switched to default wordpress theme Twenty seventeen also. still showing issue .

Comment: when i tired with a dummy container id in tag script, site working fine. When giving our own container id then its making problem,. So my doubt is, is any issue happened with container creation.

Comment: Hmm. I'd check that your plugin is generating the correct script, matching Google's latest documentation, in case it is out-of-date. Assuming that's right you might have to ask Google for help.

Comment: yes i  submitted my issue, but no reply. Thanks